# Mockito verify fails with Wanted but not invoked but it actually works

Tags: java, testing, mockito, refactoring

I'm trying to do a refactor of some ifs that sonar os crying about. Before the refactor, the code looks like this:

```
if (isRTVCreatedEventType(eventType)) {
      schemaName = RTV_CREATE_SYSTEM_SCHEMA_MAP.get(alfredEventHeader.getSource());
      if (MerchandiseReturnToVendorCreateConfirmed.getClassSchema().getName().equals(schemaName)) {
        return buildMerchandiseReturnToVendorCreate(alfredInventoryEvent);
      }
      if (StoreReturnToVendorCreated.getClassSchema().getName().equals(schemaName)) {
        return buildStoreReturnToVendorCreate(alfredInventoryEvent);
      }
}
```

So I added the methods to a map and call it like this

```
 private final Map<String, Function<AlfredInventoryEvent, SpecificRecordBase>> rtvEventBuilders = Map.ofEntries(
      Map.entry(MerchandiseReturnToVendorCreateConfirmed.getClassSchema().getName(), this::buildMerchandiseReturnToVendorCreate),
      Map.entry(MerchandiseReturnToVendorCancelConfirmed.getClassSchema().getName(), this::buildMerchandiseReturnToVendorCancel),
      Map.entry(MerchandiseReturnToVendorShipmentConfirmed.getClassSchema().getName(), this::buildMerchandiseReturnToVendorShipment),
      Map.entry(MerchandiseReturnToVendorUpdateConfirmed.getClassSchema().getName(), this::buildMerchandiseReturnToVendorUpdate),
      Map.entry(StoreReturnToVendorCreated.getClassSchema().getName(), this::buildStoreReturnToVendorCreate),
      Map.entry(StoreReturnToVendorCanceled.getClassSchema().getName(), this::buildStoreReturnToVendorCancel),
      Map.entry(StoreReturnToVendorShipped.getClassSchema().getName(), this::buildStoreReturnToVendorShipment),
      Map.entry(StoreReturnToVendorUpdated.getClassSchema().getName(), this::buildStoreReturnToVendorUpdate)
  );

if (isRTVCreatedEventType(eventType)) {
      schemaName = RTV_CREATE_SYSTEM_SCHEMA_MAP.get(alfredEventHeader.getSource());
      return rtvEventBuilders.get(schemaName).apply(alfredInventoryEvent);
}
```

I didn't modify anything in the test class, but I'm getting this error:

Wanted but not invoked:

```
rtvEnhancer.getLookupCodes(
    <any>,
    <any>,
    [CodeTypeRequest.EventCode(codeType=FromDisposition, codeValue=ATS), CodeTypeRequest.EventCode(codeType=ToDisposition, codeValue=DIST), CodeTypeRequest.EventCode(codeType=ReasonCode, codeValue=DRT)],
    RTV
);
```

-> at com.inventory.alfred.enhancement.AbstractEnhancerMapper.getLookupCodes(AbstractEnhancerMapper.java:172)

But debbuging it, it actually works and the assertion is correct. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that this code

```
rtvEnhancer.getLookupCodes(
    <any>,
    <any>,
    [CodeTypeRequest.EventCode(codeType=FromDisposition, codeValue=ATS), CodeTypeRequest.EventCode(codeType=ToDisposition, codeValue=DIST), CodeTypeRequest.EventCode(codeType=ReasonCode, codeValue=DRT)],
    RTV);
```

is called then probably one of the argument does not overrides `equals()` and mockito cant match actual arguments with stubbed ones. Without equals they are matched by Object.equals() which is memory address.
My guess is `CodeTypeRequest.EventCode`

Comment: But why it just happens when I invoke the method through the map?
The stubbing is the same and also returns what I need

Comment: This is not an awnser but a comment...

Comment: @Juan Pablo Tobon you need to provide more code since we don't see in code where `rtvEnhancer.getLookupCodes()` is called